# Is it advisable to install Windows 7 64 bit on a machine optimized for 32 bit Vista

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have several machines that are running with 32 bit Vista and I want to upgrade them to Windows 7. Since the processors in the machines say they are optimized for 32 bit, should I stay with 32 bit Windows 7 or is it ok to use 64 bit? I already re-built one machine using 64 bit Windows 7 and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: "the processors in the machines say they are optimized for 32 bit" doesn't make much sense to me.  Either they support 64-bit operation or they don't - I'd be curious what specifically you're reading that says this.

Comment: What CPU does your PC have?  If it is capable of 64-bit, you should use it.  Core2 CPUs, Core i3/5/7, AMD 64x, etc are all examples of 64-bit capable CPUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the processor is only capable of 32 bit, it can't support 64 bit, therefore if you attempt to install 64bit OS, it won't work.

Comment: Ok, So the processor is an Intel Core 2 Duo which is a 64 bit processor. It was shipped with a Dell Optiplex 360 which had Vista 32 bit installed. A co-worker was under the impression that it was somehow "optimized" for 32 bit. I think I'll go thr 64 bit route. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: With a Core2 Duo, you should be safe to install 64-bit Windows.  Been there, done that and it works mighty nicely.

Comment: You did not mention in the post it was a 64 bit processor, actually it seems like you were suggesting it was 32 bit, either way a 64bit processor can run either 32 or 64bit OS's.

Answer (score -1):

You need Intel Virtualization Technology to emulate a 64-bit OS on your 32-bit OS.
You have to confirm that your CPU supports it.